# Vortex shedding

Tags: fluid-dynamics, electricity, vortex, building-physics, piezoelectric

So I was reading about [vortex shedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_shedding), and got to know that it causes the building to resonate. Is there any way to use this resonance to generate electricity (maybe use quartz?)
I am  trying to make this model for a science fair. I am in grade 9 so it would help if the answers are not too complicated.
Thanks.

Comment: This movie might be interesting for you: http://fuckyeahfluiddynamics.tumblr.com/post/74947730170/vortex-shedding-frequently-happens-in-the-wakes-of

Comment: @Bernhard , the link you provided just describes vortex shedding, but still, thanks. It was quite informative. :)

Comment: I was talking about the movie, because it clearly demonstrates this resonance in the simple flow geometry :)

Answer (score -2):

Piezoelectricity requires a dielectric (electrically insulating body) or things internally short.  High voltage but near zero current obtain.  When the body relaxes, things reverse. One solution is an AC piezo-generator stack that is huge surface and minimum volume, driving a step down transformer or some such.  Consider piezoelecric sneaker lights and anti-static guns for vinyl records (ask your grandparents).

Infiltrate and cover your building with taut PVDF tweeter sheet, then borrow or diddle the circuitry.  
"Self-damping skyscrapers as energy generators"

(Making a Shroud of Turin only requires heavy white cloth, some plaster, and a kitchen oven. It will get you publicity if not notoriety.)

Comment: Will it work if I use cardboard for the building and cover it with PVDF?

Comment: Do your chair parade. You need a stack of taut polled elements.  http://www.piezo.com/tech2intropiezotrans.html  Six months in the lab will save you an afternoon in the library.